# Is there standard terminology for the doneness of bacon strips?

Tags: language, bacon, heat, vocabulary

As you lower temperature on strips of bacon, you go from:

- a light, hot sear (very soft, chewy bacon), to
- a hot sear followed by a light saute in its own lard (getting towards al dente), to
- a medium temperature and longer saute (a little crumbly but fundamentally staying together), to
- a low-medium temperature and very long saute (brown, disintegrates immediately).

What vocabulary would I use to describe these different options?

Comment: Are you asking about cooking method (how to cook bacon) or how the resulting bacon is ?( chewy, crispy...)

Comment: @Max Either might work, since an adverbial on how it was cooked can transfer to an adjective on how the bacon is, but I am fundamentally interested in how the resulting bacon is.